# Play Console Crash - abort / signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: flutter

I have weird crashes reported to my Crashes/ANR section of Play Console, but they are really hard to debug since
the crash don't seem to be symbolicated.

Devices seem to be mostly Samsung devices, and Android 8,9 and 10.

Here is the stacktraces:

I get either

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.xxx.android <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000004af5dc  /data/app/com.xxx.android-9wnzDk9Dr2uZCCXc2_3W_g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x88c000)
```

or

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.xxx.android <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000001cece  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+58)
  #00  pc 0000000000a1a857  /data/app/com.xxx.android-Ra4Eu1ajkldMMOzlA1iGeg==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk (offset 0x9fd000)
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.25.0-9.0.pre.15, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.25.0-9.0.pre.15 at /Users/oscar/flutter
    • Framework revision c2bfb7b348 (4 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 08:33:04 +0800
    • Engine revision d2ccdefe18
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-135.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/oscar/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.2, Build version 12B45b
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 87.0.4280.88

• No issues found!
```

How can I debug this deeper and maybe identify what exactly causes the crash?

Comment: Do you have Crashlytics configured?

Comment: @DarshShah sadly I do not.

Comment: did you find a way to handle it?

Comment: No sir, I don't work with Flutter anymore